# Basic indexing on axis with MultiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

This is my multiIndex dataframe gotten from groupby where I have 2 indexes [ 'YearMonth', 'product_id'] and column name ['count'] I've tried examples from [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#cross-section) and other stackoverflow suggestions  but still cannot index **product_id** == 6818 for each YearMonth index column.

```
df = df.groupby(['YearMonth','product_id'])[['count']].sum()
df.head(5)
Out[54]:

                      count
YearMonth   product_id  
2017-05-01  6818    3
7394    1   7394    1
8369    1   8369    1
8504    1   8504    1
8666    1   8666    1



In [55]:
df.columns
Out[55]:
Index(['count'], dtype='object')
In [56]:
df.index.names
Out[56]:
FrozenList(['YearMonth', 'product_id'])
In [59]:
df.loc[('2017-05-01',0),'count']
```

I've tried: simple indexing `df['YearMonth']` but it only works with columns not indexes

**df.loc\ix\iloc** as was given in this  [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819233/indexing-on-dataframe-with-multiindex)

```
df.loc[('2017-05-01',0)]
```

Always I get KeyError such as `KeyError: ('2017-05-01', 0)` , `KeyError: 'YearMonth'`

as well as I did a try to **unstack** method `df.unstack(level=0)` and did the same manipulations as written above

May someone explain what am I missing? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample DF doesn't look "healthy" - i have fixed it so it looks like as follows now:

```
In [121]: df
Out[121]:
                       count
YearMonth  product_id
2017-05-01 6818            3
           7394            1
           8369            1
           8504            1
           8666            1
```

**Option 1:**

```
In [122]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, 6818], :]
Out[122]:
                       count
YearMonth  product_id
2017-05-01 6818            3
```

**Option 2:**  works for named indices

```
In [145]: df.query("product_id in [6818]")
Out[145]:
                       count
YearMonth  product_id
2017-05-01 6818            3
```

**Option 3:**

```
In [146]: df.loc[(slice(None), 6818), :]
Out[146]:
                       count
YearMonth  product_id
2017-05-01 6818            3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Kinda all seems strange for me now. I didn't used to working with multipleindex dataframes. Your help is awesome

Comment: @IvanShelonik, glad I could help :)